# Spark read from second row like Pandas header=1

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Pandas with Python I could use:

`for item in read_csv(csv_file, header=1)`

And in Spark I only have the option of true/false?

`df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load('myfile.csv')`

How can I read starting from the second row in Spark?
The suggested duplicate post is an outdated version of Spark. I am using the latest, 2.4.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip lines while reading a CSV file as a dataFrame using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077404/how-to-skip-lines-while-reading-a-csv-file-as-a-dataframe-using-pyspark) - refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44080537/5858851).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's no option in spark csv to specify how many lines to skip. Here are some alternatives you can try:

1. Read with `option("header", "true")`, and rename the column names using `withColumnRenamed`.
2. Read with `option("header", "false")`, and select rows from 2nd line using select.
3. If the first character of the first line is different from all other lines, you can use `comment` option to skip it. For example, if the first character of line #1 is `D`, you set `comment='D'`. Just be careful, `comment` will skip any line that starts with `D` here.

Hope this helps.