# When reading a CSV is there an option to start on row 2 or below?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm reading a bunch of CSV files into a dataframe using the sample code below.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("sep","|")
   .option("inferSchema","true")
   .option("header","false")
   .load("mnt/rawdata/corp/ABC*.gz")
```

I'm hoping there is a way to start on row 2 or below, because row 1 contains some basic metadata about these files, and the first row has 4 pipe characters, so Spark thinks the file has 4 columns, but it actually has over 100 columns in the actual data.

I tried playing with the inferSchema and header but I couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip lines while reading a CSV file as a dataFrame using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077404/how-to-skip-lines-while-reading-a-csv-file-as-a-dataframe-using-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right!  You need to define a custom schema!  I ended up going with this.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name

val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("field1", StringType, true),
    StructField("field2", StringType, true),
    StructField("field3", StringType, true),
    StructField("field4", StringType, true),
    StructField("field5", StringType, true),
    StructField("field6", StringType, true),
    StructField("field7", StringType, true)))

val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("sep", "|")
    .schema(customSchema)
    .load("mnt/rawdata/corp/ABC*.gz")
    .withColumn("file_name", input_file_name())
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first line in CSV doesnt match actual column count and names, you may need to define your schema by hand, and then try this combination:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("sep","|")
   .option("inferSchema","false")
   .option("header","true")     
   .schema(mySchema)
   .option("enforceSchema","true")
   .load(...
```

[Full list of CSV options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-scala.collection.Seq-).

Note that for Spark 2.3 and above, you can use a shorthand, SQL-style notation for schema definition -- simple string `"column1 type1, column2 type2, ..."`.

If however your header has more than one line, you will probably be forced to ignore all "errors" by using additional option `.option("mode","DROPMALFORMED")`.