# Reading first N lines of all files via Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If we exclude utilities and RDD nested zipping of filenames via zipWithIndex, what are the elegant options of for *every* file to be processed, to remove / *skip the first N* records? *Where N > 1*.

A few of the presented options here seem to work with first line.

Comment: You can use something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152940/16676737

Comment: For all files not just 1 file @Bondarenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work at the cost of a shuffle

```scala
import org.apache.sql.functions._
import org.apache.sql.expressions.Window

val ROWS_TO_SKIP=5
val filtered_df = df
  .withColumn("__file", input_file_name())
  .withColumn("__idx", monotonicallyIncreasingId())
  .withColumn("__file_idx", row_number().over(
        Window.partitionBy('__file).orderBy('__idx))
  )
  .filter('__file_idx > ROWS_TO_SKIP)
  .drop("__file","__idx","__file_idx")
```

Comment: Does not work and old syntax as well. I read an rdd first that may be issue I will check tonight with spark.read

Comment: It works for me on a simple 4 files csv data frame on spark 3.1.2. If it does not work on your data, I would be interested in understanding why.

Comment: I will get back later.

Comment: I had sc wholeTextFiles hanging around